# Display data in chart form

Tags: asp.net-core

There are a lot of data in my database, how can I display them in report form? What I understand is a Crystal Reports, but the Crystal Reports SDK seems to only support the Framework framework. Mine is an asp.net core project. How do I do it?Need this style[image]

Comment: You could do it client-side with a js library like Google Charts. Or use a library to render images on the server-side -- this would just be images you display to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use `Chart.js` to handle this kind of scenario. You could have
> a try below sample to achieve what you are trying to. Additionally, you can have a look on [official document](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html) for any kind of customization.

***`HTML:`***

```cs
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

***`Chart.js Script:`***

```cs
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var data = {
  labels: ["2020", "2021", "2022"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Green",
    backgroundColor: "#3A5721",
    data: [3, 7, 4]
  }, {
    label: "Orange",
    backgroundColor: "#F6833B",
    data: [4, 3, 5]
  }, {
    label: "Yellow",
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
    data: [7, 2, 6]
  }]
};

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    barValueSpacing: 20,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

***`Output:`***

[image]

***`Js fiddle Example:`***

> You have have look on the real life example and source file example on
> [`jsfiddle.net`](https://jsfiddle.net/faridkiron/7ab4xhpv/6/)

***`Js Reference Required:`***

> You need following reference on your project.
>
> `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.bundle.js`

Hope above steps guided you accordingly.